# android Jackson parsing with JSONArrays

Tags: android, json, jackson

So I'm really not seeing what I'm doing wrong with the JSON parsing. It won't parse JSONArrays. I've tested it with just regular JSON objects and it works fine but arrays seem to trip it up

Here's my JSON file

```
    {
    "list": [
        {
            "field_one": "HI",
            "field_two": "Hi, AGAIN"
        },
        {
            "field_one": "hola",
            "field_two": "konnbanwa"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's my class to put the JSON data in

```
public class Test implements Serializable {
public ArrayList<List> list;

public ArrayList<List> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(ArrayList<List> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public class List implements Serializable {
    public String field_one;
    public String field_two;

    public String getField_one() {
        return field_one;
    }

    public void setField_one(String field_one) {
        this.field_one = field_one;
    }

    public String getField_two() {
        return field_two;
    }

    public void setField_two(String field_two) {
        this.field_two = field_two;
    }


   }
}
```

And here's where I map the values into the class....

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setVisibilityChecker(
                mapper.getVisibilityChecker()
                        .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY));
        Test test = mapper.readValue(json, Test.class);
```

Comment: What is happening that you are not expecting?

Comment: Sorry I'll edit the post.
It's just not parsing at all. It's getting hung up on the list objects it seems. I can parse normal JSONObjects but not arrays.